# App-debug Working but Signed App-release giving Unfortunately Stopped

Tags: javascript, android, gridle

generated a signed apk, the signed apk does not working, the signed apk givinf unfortunately stopped, Whereas the app-debug is working perfectly.

Please help me to fix the issue....

Comment: please give the logcat error after running the app in release mode

Comment: is debug apk working fine. i mean have to tried copy the file into device and install else sending into mail have you tried. Instead connecting cable to system and running.